# Add new row at first on TableView IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, object, addition

I want to update data in `tableView` and get new data inserted as the new initial rows in a `UITableView`.
I have two arrays: `FileName` Array contains data that I get from the server using `ParseXM` and a temp array used to copy from `FileNameArray`. I wrote a function `UpdateArray` to get new data, I copy data from `FileNameArray` to temp array in `ViewDidLoad()` and then call `UpdateArray`; first I remove all entries in `FileNameArray`, send a request to the server calling `ParseXML` thereafter, then I compare `FileNameArray` and temp Array, if `FileName arr > temp arr` : remove all entries in `temp arr` and copy from `FileName` arr to `temp arr`, then reload data for `UITableview` but `tableView` does not show new data in the first row(s).

**cellForRowAtIndexPath():**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSArray* FileNamereversed = [[FileCompletedArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
    NSArray* UploadTimereversed = [[UploadTimeArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        UILabel *FileNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
        FileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        FileNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        NSLog(@"Reseversed TEMP array %@",FileNamereversed);
        FileNameLabel.text =[FileNamereversed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: FileNameLabel];
        [FileNameLabel release];

        UILabel *UploadTimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 25)];

        UploadTimeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UploadTimeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        UploadTimeLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        UploadTimeLabel.text = [UploadTimereversed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: UploadTimeLabel];
        [UploadTimeLabel release];

        UILabel *CompleteLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 12, 170, 25)];
        CompleteLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        CompleteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        CompleteLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        CompleteLabel.text =@"Completed";
        CompleteLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: CompleteLabel];
        [CompleteLabel release];
    }
    //[temp removeAllObjects];
   // temp = [FileCompletedArray mutableCopy];
        return cell;
}
```

**Update Array ():**

```
-(void)updateArray{
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4.0];

        [FileCompletedArray removeAllObjects];
...
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];

        [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
            NSString * parsexmlinput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response in Loop CompleteView: %@", parsexmlinput); //000400010001
           // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self parseXMLFile:parsexmlinput];

            NSLog(@"File Completed array: %@", FileCompletedArray);
            NSLog(@"File Temp out array: %@", temp);
            NSLog(@"File Completed count: %lu",(unsigned long)[ FileCompletedArray count]);
            NSLog(@"File Temp out count: %lu", (unsigned long)[temp count]);
            // NSLog(@"State: %@", state);
            if([FileCompletedArray count ] != [temp count]) // compare 2 array
            {
                [temp removeallObjects];
                temp = [FileCompletedArray mutableCopy];
                [_tableView reloadData];

            }
            else
            {
               NSLog(@"2 array equal");
            }

}
```

When I call `UpdateArray`, although server has new data but the two arrays equal each other so my `tableView` does not update.
Can you show me the solution? Thanks in advance.

editor's remark:
the original wording was close to unintelligible - in correcting I might have missed or misread some aspects. the original author is strongly encouraged to proof-read.

Comment: please put some code here for what you have to tried ?

Comment: first update the array before [tableview reloadData]

Comment: What did you try so far, where is your code if you did????

Answer (score 0):

For updating the table view you have to update your array as per your requirement.

1. You can add object to as: `[yourArray insertObject:object atIndex:0];` `//for first row.`
2. Then reload table with new array :`[yourTable reloadData]`

this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**@V-Xtreme answer is right and another option is...**

And also For do this types of work you need to use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` Method such like

```
[self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:YES ];
```

Where indexPath contains the row number that you want to add it.

Comment: he want new data to be at the top then how can you use this ?